# How to join blank table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to fetch all the rows from my 3 tables and one of them is empty.

Table 1:

```
Names  Numbers
Hello  123
Bye    123
```

Table 2:

```
Names  Numbers
Xyz.   246
```

Table 3:

```
Names  Numbers
```

Table 3 doesn't contain any values

I want the result to contain all the rows like this:

```
Names  Numbers
Xyz.   246
Hello  123
Bye    123
```

Comment: Use a `UNION`, not a `JOIN`

Comment: Revision #3 drastically changed the question and I have rolled it back. For more discussion see [this chat transcript](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/23858149#23858149)

Comment: Look up the questions this OP has asked.. they have all been the same

Comment: This question and the duplicate(s) the OP asked are a complete disaster. Lacking enough details for a reasonable response and just all over the place. This person is either a troll or far over their head for us to help.

Comment: Curios if the person that edited the question "AsConfused" stands for "Abhishek Singh Confused"

Comment: No argument on the fact that these questions aren't great quality (OP - Please go look up some SQL tutorials! And have a read through the help section on asking questions before you ask more.). There's definitely some overlap between some of them, but editing one question to match the others isn't a good way to fix it. It caused some correct answers to suddenly be incorrect, because it did significantly change the nature of this question.

Answer (score 2):

I think You are looking for **`Union all`**

```
select * from table1
union all
select * from table2
union all
select * from table3
```

**Join** Use to **combine Columns** While **Union** use to **Combine Rows**

Answer (score 0):

To get all of these values you have to ... get all the records :)

```
SELECT Name, Numbers FROM Table1
UNION 
SELECT Name, Numbers FROM Table2
UNION 
SELECT Name, Numbers FROM Table3
```

Comment: Beware on this solution, it may be slow on bigger tables because of the implicit distinct. If you can guarantee that you won't have any duplicates. Better use union all.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `UNION` to get your distinct list of names
2. Use `LEFT JOIN` to retrieve your data

Example:

```
SELECT list.names, t1.assigned, t2.unsassigned, t3.closed, t4.open
FROM 
   (select names from table1
    union select names from table2
    union select names from table3
    union select names from table4
   ) list
LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON (list.names = t1.names)
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON (list.names = t2.names)
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON (list.names = t3.names)
LEFT JOIN table4 t4 ON (list.names = t4.names)
```

Comment: Check the question's edit history - it just needed the unions as per the original answers, then someone edited it and completely changed the meaning. Needs a rollback but I don't have enough rep.

Comment: 4 different people have edited the question and 2 of them had really low ratings (one being the OP) - my guess is the OP has two accounts, which is not permitted.  I also suppose that "Numbers" was used more as a datatype than a field name and the question that stands is more likely the initial intended question.

Comment: It's rolled back now. Someone other than the OP thought that two different questions were duplicates, but when you look at them, they are fundamentally different. One needed unions, the other needed joins. Different numbers of tables and different fields. Someone in the review queue did catch it and rejected it, but everyone else just robo-reviewed it through. Anyway, all sorted now.