# How to join blank tables

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Table1

```
Names   assigned
Xyz.        123
Wxy.        456
```

Table 2

```
Names. Unassigned
Xyz.        789
Tty.        123
```

Table 3

```
Names.    Closed
Wxy.        456
Twr.        123
```

Table 4

```
Names.  Open
```

This table doesn't contain any values

I want output like

```
Names   assigned      unassigd      closed     open
Xyz.       123.          789.          0.        0
Wxy.       0             457.          0.        0          
Tty.       0             123.          0.        0  
Twr.       0             0             123.      0
```

How to join them?

Comment: Can you provide a demo create statement or give a bit more detail what you want to achieve?

Comment: Please provide the create table statements. What u provided was painful

Comment: Create table table1(name varchar,number int)

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30804164/how-to-join-blank-table

Comment: The question was in complete in that questions I mentioned like all the columns are same, but I have only name column same all other column are different

Comment: But this is the same thing. And sadly just like your other question you aren't providing much if any information. We can help and most of us are really good at sql, but are pretty bad at mind reading.

Comment: My 1st 3 tables contains column but the last table doesn't contain any values for some specific date ,but for Some other date my all the tables contain the values!

Comment: I would highly recommend you read this article. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: A cut and paste from dev tool in question area EDIT above not free form

Comment: I have tried full outer join but it only works if all the table have some value ,but in case a table doesn't contain any value then it doesn't join

Comment: Incorporate outer join concept

Comment: That because a join requires rows. That is how they work. When there are no rows in one of the tables there are no rows that meet the join criteria. That is why it has been suggested to use UNION or UNION ALL or OUTER JOIN

Comment: I have used full outer join and I am joining based on names,what should I try?

Comment: Can you delete this question and we move back to orig one?

Comment: My previous question was not in proper shape! Can you please suggest me how to join such table

Comment: You need to ask a proper question before we can provide an answer. http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/05/13/question-needed-not-answer.aspx

Comment: I have your question from here in my clipboard. I will edit your orig question. Delete this one

Comment: Plus your orig question had an answer we can stare at

Comment: How to delete my previous question

Comment: There is a delete link under the question. But delete this question as the other has answers. Then perform edit to other question

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT
    n.NAMES,
    ISNULL(t1.Assigned, 0) Assigned,
    ISNULL(t1.Unassigned, 0) Unassigned,
    ISNULL(t1.Closed, 0) Closed,
    ISNULL(t1.Open, 0) Open
FROM
    (           SELECT NAMES FROM Table1
        UNION   SELECT NAMES FROM Table2
        UNION   SELECT NAMES FROM Table3
        UNION   SELECT NAMES FROM Table4
    ) AS n
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT NAMES, SUM(Assigned) FROM Table1 GROUP BY NAMES) t1 ON n.NAMES = t1.NAMES
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT NAMES, SUM(Unassigned) FROM Table2 GROUP BY NAMES) t2 ON n.NAMES = t2.NAMES
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT NAMES, SUM(Closed) FROM Table3 GROUP BY NAMES) t3 ON n.NAMES = t3.NAMES
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT NAMES, SUM(Open) FROM Table4 GROUP BY NAMES) t4 ON n.NAMES = t4.NAMES
```

Comment: but in case if the 1st table contain 3 records and table 2 contain 5 records then it will take only 3 reords

Comment: create a sql fiddle so we can see what you're talking about